# How to deploy a contract with many arguments?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Hello guys  I have contract with many arguments, when I deploy it with .deploy() function am getting error that there are expected arguments. This is how my contrract constructor looks like.

```
 constructor(
    address _manager,
    string memory name,
    string memory description,
    string memory imageHash,
    uint256 price,
    string[] memory moduleNames,
    string[] memory moduleDescriptions,
    string[] memory materialHashes,
    string[] memory questionHashes
) {
    //contructor sets manager as contract creator
    manager = _manager;
    tokenHoldersCounter = 1;
    tokenHolders[0] = manager;
    numOfMaintainers = 1;
    balance[manager] = 500;
    tokenPot = 500;
    dadAddress = msg.sender;
    courseName = name;
    courseDescription = description;
    courseImageHash = imageHash;
    coursePrice = price;
    pushModules(
        moduleNames,
        moduleDescriptions,
        materialHashes,
        questionHashes
    );
}
```

how should declare the arguments in .deploy() function

Comment: Can you share your .deploy() function?

Comment: It is likely some of the parameters are undefined, so those parameters will appear to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

you have 9 arguments in the constructor(). constructor() is executed along with the contract deployment. so you need to provide all the arguments of constructor with contract deploy() function as shown below.

e.g.

```
const MyContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
this.myContract = await MyContract.deploy(managerAddress, name, description, imageHash, price, moduleNames, moduleDescriptions, materialHashes, questionHashes);
```